# Regex matches on regxr but not in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a regex:

```
^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)-SNAPSHOT$
```

This matches `1.30.0-SNAPSHOT` using [regexr](https://regexr.com):

I now tried to check this in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
REGEX="^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)-SNAPSHOT$"
VERSION="1.30.O-SNAPSHOT"
if [[ $VERSION =~ $REGEX ]]
then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "not"
```

This prints not

Comment: Bash doesn't have `\d`. Use `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: Beside using `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, you have the capital letter `O` instead of `0` after `30.` Is it a typo?

Comment: Use: `'^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*-SNAPSHOT$'` as regex

Comment: See https://ideone.com/8vlHBz